# Certain IDs not being modified in CSS, how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, tags

If I assign the ID `Test` to a section in HTML and modify that in CSS, the text is modified. But, when I change it to an ID like `About` the CSS no longer works on the text, and it's just normal `<p>` formatting. How do I fix this?

```
<section id="About">
     <p>We define a Christian as someone who affirms the <a href="/nicene" rel="nicene">Nicene Creed</a></p>
</section>
```

```
#About
    {
      text-align: left;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: well without providing the codes you using, there is no way to anwser you with 100% certainty. So please provide the code that has been asked for already.

Comment: I haven’t been able to provide it yet. I apologize. @tacoshy

Comment: @tacoshy I will get it as soon as possible.

Comment: works fine for me. Have you already cleared your cache? or refreshed the page?

Comment: Ah, completely forgot about the cache issue. Fixed now. Thanks!